# Indent / pad text in TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using both `TextField` and `TextEditor`, as I need single and multi-line text input. I'm targeting iOS 15+, so can't just use `TextField` with linelimit, as it's iOS 16+.

```swift
TextField("placeholder", text: "Hello world")
    .padding(10)

TextEditor(text: "Hello world")
    .frame(height: 100)
    .cornerRadius(14)
```

See this image:

[image]

The `TextField` has the text slightly indented, compared with the `TextEditor`. How do I indent the `TextEditor` input text? I've tried using `.padding` but can't find a way to get it to just target the text — I'm only able to pad the frame of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a `background` to the `TextEditor`, and making that have the rounded corners, rather than the `TextEditor` itself…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var field: String = "Hello World"
    @State private var editor: String = "Hello World"
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("What is the") {
                TextField("placeholder", text: $field)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(14)
                    .listRowBackground(Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground))
            }

            Section("Longer text") {
                TextEditor(text: $editor)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .listRowBackground(Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground))
                    .padding(5)
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
                            .fill(.white)
                    }
            }
        }
        .background(Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground))
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution (as TextEditor is actually UITextView) is to use appearance. So the answer would be to add the following in the parent view of `TextEditor`

```
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().textContainerInset =
        UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 0)   // << !!
    }
    var body: some View {
           TextEditor(text: "Hello world")
              .frame(height: 100)
              .cornerRadius(14)
    }
```